# Django Reverse the mapper, URL name doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I'm currently doing on Django project and using reversing the mapper on urls.py. Before I use reversing it worked well, but after I change it to reversing, it started to do not work anymore.
I want to know why it doesn't work. Is it because I didn't add it in proejct file's urls.py? How can I call that url with the name in app's file?

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'posting'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:post_id>', views.post, name='post'),
    path('posting', views.posting, name='postingform')
]
```

index.html

```
<a href='{% url 'postingform' %}'>Upload your beer now!</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you defined an `app_name` in your `urls.py`, yo need to specify the name of the view *with* the `app_name`:

```
<a href='{% url 'posting:postingform' %}'>Upload your beer now!</a>
```